# Assign one textbox selected value to another one in JQuery Auto Complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to assign one textbox's selected value to another textbox. I am using below script for this. When I am checking in Firefox Browser Console, I noticed that state variable (c_search.php?state) has no value.

Please let me know what changes I need to do with script.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#statename" ).autocomplete({
          source: 'search.php'
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $( "#cityname" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'c_search.php?state='+$('#statename').val()
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="statename">State: </label>
    <input id="statename">

    <label for="cityname">City: </label>
    <input id="cityname">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: The statement that executes `$('#statename').val()` is part of your binding to `#cityname`. Are you sure that statename has text when the autocomplete event is fired for cityname?

Comment: Yes, I am able to enter and select state from statename textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for autocompletechange change method like this-

Also your input field declaration looks weird to me.Keep in mind you should not load DOM multiple times like the way you are doing now.

It should be

```
<input type="text" id="statename" class="inputLarge" />
```

And autocomplete change event is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#statename').on('autocompletechange change', function () {

    $("[name='some text box']").val(this.value);
    PopulateCitybyState(this.value);    

}).change();
});

function PopulateCitybyState(statename){
   $( "#cityname" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'c_search.php?state='+ statename
    });
}
```

Comment: How can I declare search.php and c_search.php urls in above script? Can you please clarify with some more details.

Comment: you create a separate function where you pass  this.value as parameter and write auto complete there with this passed value.

Comment: I am new to jQuery so currently I want to keep state and city functions separate. But still I am not able to understand your code and make required changes in my code so it works properly. Ty...

Comment: see my update now..Also being new is not an excuse to do things without proper/recommended way.

Comment: Ty for your help. It works for me now. Can you please one do thing? Please mention search.php file in your answer so it can be useful for other too. I can't edit your answer that's why I am requesting you. Ty again...